# Installation issues for tensorflow-decision-forests on Linux

Tags: python, linux, docker, tensorflow, machine-learning

I getting the following error trying to install [tensorflow-decision-forests](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests) on Fedora 38 with `pip install tensorflow-decision-forests`:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-decision-forests (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-decision-forests
```

So I tried following [installation-build](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/main/documentation/installation.md)

Doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests.git 
cd decision-forests/tools
```

then,

```
./test_bazel.sh
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow== (from
versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.13.0rc0) ERROR: No matching distribution
found for tensorflow==
```

So then I tried with docker since I have it installed:

```
./tools/start_compile_docker.sh
```

inside docker:

```
./tools/test_bazel.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow== (from
versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1,
2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0,
2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4,
2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2,
2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1,
2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.13.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow== tf-docker
```

Any help?

Comment: `tensorflow==` does not look well-formed; does `test-bezel.sh` require an argument, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: TF-DF 1.3.0 now also has a Python 3.11 version available on Pypi

TF-DF 1.3.0 does not support Python 3.11 (but I am confident it will do so with the next version). Since AFAICT Fedora 38 uses Python 3.11, this is the most likely cause of your issue. The easiest fix for your problem would be to use a different Python version -- 3.8 - 3.10 are supported.

Compiling TF-DF yourself can be a bit tricky. Your best bet would be indeed to start the docker and then run test_bazel.sh with the following arguments.

```
RUN_TESTS=0 PY_VERSION=3.8 TF_VERSION=2.12.0 ./tools/test_bazel.sh
```

You can play with the arguments to make it work, details are in the header of `test_bazel.sh`.

Full Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of Tensorflow Decision Forests.

Comment: I appreciate your time for this answer. I've install python version 3.8 using dnf, then ran test_bazel.sh with the docker command you've suggested. Then I was able to install tensorflow_decision_forests for with pip install tensorflow_decision_forests and now able to use it with the python3.8 kernel! Thank you so much!